# POCO class properties determined on-the-fly relative to other instances of the same class

Tags: c#, collections, architecture, poco

I have a weird question that I'm struggling to get my head around, about where in a business model to house a particular sort of logic. Specifically, in a POCO getter-only property that returns a value evaluated in relation to all the other instances in existence of the same class object.

For example, say I have a POCO class "foo" with a get/set property called "Value", type currency. Then another property in "foo" called "Percentile", which is just a simple getter, type int, with a formula intended to return that particular instance of foo's percentile in relation to all the instances of Foo in existence in the system.

A similar scenario might be that of a Document class, where a Document instance could logically "know" it's own Status in relation to all the other documents in the system. E.g. A particular Document in a series being able to return IsLatest = true, whilst all the other instances in that series returned false. Then if another user added a new document, after repolling the property the true on that first instance would re-evaluate to false.

This feels to me to be legitimate / reasonable business logic to need to model and have calculated on the fly from temporal database tables without having to constantly update/ maintain those values in the persistent store.

But I think the way I'm approaching it smells bad, as it only leads back to my individual instances needing to know about all the other instances held in memory, or being able to execute queries against the persistent store lazily whenever the property in question is polled.

There must be a more elegant solution or approach to this problem?

How should I approach handling collections of POCO's, where the collection affects some of the calculated properties in its members??

Comment: *"with a formula intended to return that particular instance of foo's percentile in relation to all the instances of Foo in existence in the system."* Are you already keeping track of all instances in the system? Seems like something the client would want to do by creating a collection of your class instead (or a different class that exposes instances as a collection). This definitely smells bad to me. What if the consumer of your class wants two separate, independent collections of your class? It would be helpful if you gave a real world example of what you're referring to.

Comment: I haven't written the client use cases yet, I was just initially trying to write the core poco entities. I will have a collection of all the entities, yes. But allowing the entities to reference that seemed to create a dependency in the wrong direction!? I thought about using an interface to such a collection, but again that feels like a bad smell to me for some reason??

Comment: If we think of a deck of cards as an example, a deck is a collection of `Card` objects (like a `Queue<Card>`, `Stack<Card>`, `List<Card>`, or custom class that implements `IEnumerable<Card>`. But it's the `Deck` that knows about the `Card` objects. The `Card` objects know nothing of each other. To get the total value, you might do `var total = Deck.Sum(card => card.Value);`. If you wanted to get the probability of choosing an `Ace`, you would do something like `var aceProbability = Deck.Count(card => card.Value == CardValue.Ace) / Deck.Count();`. What specifically are you trying to model?

Comment: Specifically it's a weird workflow status on documents in a system. All the documents will be browsable in a datagrid, and they'll be colour coded based on their Workflow position, which in turn is derived from user-set document Status (or rather, the relative status of documents in a series).  Status has a number of levels the user selects from, e.g. S1 to S7, A1-A8, B1-B8, and CR. The workflow positions (colours) are effectively WIP, SHARED, PUBLISHED, ARCHIVED.

Comment: Incidentally, this is going to be a desktop WPF / MVVM client, connected to a remote multi user MySQL database via NHibernate. In which case I'm wondering whether the view model might be the place to host these collections and calculate these on-the-fly properties / colour-codings for the datagrid?

Comment: Ok, good luck. This is far too broad and opinon-based for stackoverflow, but hopefully you get it working!

Comment: Yeah I know, it's a horrible "system" / "convention" that I'm trying to make the best of in the circumstances. To be fair, your deck of cards analogy has clarified the situation a lot for me, and has now made my realise / decide that the status of the "card" relative to the "deck" is not a concern of the card. The card can not and should not know it's own probability of being higher in value than the next card in a random deck.